# VBA comparing files before moving to another folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to use a code that ensures that there is a match from the input and output folders before moving input files into another folder.  Here is a snippet:

```
'Select first Excel file within that Outlook_ImportedClaimsFiles folder path
OutlookImportFN = Dir(OutlookImportPath & "\*.xls")


'Select first Excel file within the SAS_Outputs folder path
SASOutputFN = Dir(SASOutputsPath & "\*.xls")

'Cycle through all files in the source folder path until there are no more left to cycle through
Do While OutlookImportFN <> ""
Counter = Counter + 1

    'Create full path name of the source file
    sFilePathName = OutlookImportPath & "\" & OutlookImportFN

    'Create full path name of the destination file and add the date and time the file was moved
    dFilePathName = OutlookRunPath & "\" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & OutlookImportFN
```

The problem is that in the first folder (OutlookImportFN), there is a batch/holding file that contains the filenames for all the files in that folder that is used in the overall process.  When flagging the first file, this file comes up first (this file shouldn't be flagged/selected at all).  Because of this, when doing the comparison, the files don't match (unless I start with the 2nd file in the list).  How do I either start with the 2nd file in the Input folder when comparing to the 1st file in the Output folder, or skip over this holding file in the Input folder when doing the comparison?  I've tried a few things but nothing seems to work.  Thanks in advance for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `If` statement which makes sure the file isn't that batch file:

```
Do While OutlookImportFN <> ""
Counter = Counter + 1

    If Not OutlookImportFN = "MyBatchFile" Then

    'Create full path name of the source file
    sFilePathName = OutlookImportPath & "\" & OutlookImportFN

    'Create full path name of the destination file and add the date and time the file was moved
    dFilePathName = OutlookRunPath & "\" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & OutlookImportFN

    End If
```